# K2 comments + reCaptcha issue

Tags: joomla2.5

I 've just installed reCaptcha public and private keys on my joomla 2.5 site and i found out that the K2 comments submission stopped working. All i see is a message: "Please enter the 2 words you see below" above the submit comment button but no words appear. Any ideas on this? 
K2 version: 2.6.2

Comment: I have the same problem. captcha image isnt showing.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason jQuery is not well loaded in your site. 
Do the following:

1. Go to plugin, and ensure that K2 system plugin is enabled (i.e on the back end, go to Extensions, select plugin manager, check out k2 system plugin and ensure it is enabled).
2. Ensure that you setup correctly the jQuery handling options under K2 parameters. All you need to do is go to admin back end, click under components, go to K2 component. Once it is, click on k2 parameters. Check under 'layout & views'. Check jQuery library handling; set it to  load v.1.8.2 local; also do the same under Backend jQuery & jQuery UI handling; set it to local copy.

Ensure your k2 comments are enabled and alas, everything will work.

If the above fails - I am dead sure it won't - do the following:

Make sure that there is no other javascript error on your page preventing reCAPTCHA from operating. Have in mind that you only need one copy of jQuery on your site. K2 namespaces jQuery with $K2.

Instead of the following:

```
$(document).ready ....
```

You can use the following:

```
$K2(document).ready ....
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have setup public and private key under k2 configuration into advance tab. Otherwise your captcha will not show.